# Jasmine test to check Parameters passed to Backbone sync

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

I am writing a jasmine unit test to check if BackBone sync is called with a Parameter (which is an Object).

Here is the code base

In my collection I have sync method which is calling Back Bone sync

```
sync: function ( method, collection, options ) {
            if ( !options ) {
                options = {};
            }
            options.headers = {
                “x-yz-webservice-client-id": “abcde"
            };
            return Backbone.sync( method, collection, options );
}
```

Here I want to check if options.headers of Backbone sync is set to object {
                “x-yz-webservice-client-id": “abcde"
            };

What I am trying to do in jasmine test and which is not working is as follows:

```
var headers = {
                “x-yz-webservice-client-id": “abcde"
  };
var autoCompleteRecommendationsCollection = new AutoCompleteRecommendationsCollection({},opt);
spyOn( Backbone, 'sync' );
   autoCompleteRecommendationsView.initialize( options );
expect(Backbone.sync).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.anything(),  jasmine.anything(), jasmine.objectContaining(headers));
```

I want to test this third argument has the property set to headers as above. Is there a better way to check this argument?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Jasmine v2.x, an alternative would be:

```
expect(Backbone.sync.calls.mostRecent().args[2].headers)
   .toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
       “x-yz-webservice-client-id": “abcde"
   }));
```

However there appears to be nothing wrong with your code, have you confirmed your spy is actually called? Since you are dealing with a global `Backbone` variable, you need to make sure the spec and class under test share the same one.